# wp-query with a tax-query relation of NOT

Tags: wp-query

I have an awkward problem. I'm trying to write a WP_QUERY which has a relation of NOT in the tax query.

Essentially this is what I want to achieve.

```
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'NOT',    // this doesn't work though!!
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( $country, $language ),
            'operator' => 'IN'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( $country, $language ),
            'operator' => 'AND'
        )
```

In other words, I want to retrieve posts which are tagged

**$country OR $language** (i.e. they have just ONE of these tags)

but **NOT**

**$country AND $language** (i.e. they have BOTH tags)

Any pointers would be much appreciated here!!

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? It's clear what you want, but what is the current result?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. This returns results where posts contain BOTH the $country & $language tags. I need posts with EITHER of the tags (but not both).